# How can we send Images over a MQ using LoadRunner script?

Tags: ibm-mq, performance-testing, loadrunner

Problem Statement: "We need to pass xml & image over a MQ using LoadRunner script"

The application we are testing from performance percpective needs the MQ input to be combination of xml & image.

We sorted out the xml part. Don't know how can we pass '.tiff' image to MQ using LoadRunner script.

Can someone help here please?
....

Comment: Can you treat the tiff image as binary data therefore pass a byte array?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Calanais.
Will look into its feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.  You're going to be asking lots of questions of your developers.   I have worked in a similar environment which involved the submission of biometric data over a queue with XML.   There were multiple steps, including base64 encoding of the image to fit within the XML in that case.

You need to understand precisely how the TIFF is being submitted.  Once you understand that then you should be able to come up with a programmatic model inside of LoadRunner (C, VB, Java, ...) to submit the XML and TIFF

Comment: When looked deeper at xml, there was <ImageSource>S</ImageSource> tag and some similar ones..
I am trying to understand if we can manipulate these.. and also how is the tiff exactly submitted.
Still in conversation with developers.. will keep you posted..
Thanks